# Regular expression filter my logs on date basis

Tags: regex, kubernetes, yaml

I have a log file with dates in the format of `23 Aug 2019 05:26:53`, I want to filter on date wise, I have written pattern in my yaml file as :

```
"pattern" : "\\(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) [A-Z][a-z]{2} d{4}"
```

Can you please suggest me

Comment: And what's happening with your example?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a correction to your current regex pattern:

```
(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) [A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{4}
```

The days, month name, and year components are separate by space, not dash.  However, I might just use the following simplified (though more targeted) pattern:

```
\d{1,2} [A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
```

It is highly likely that the above pattern would only target the timestamps in your log file, and it is easier to read than your version.

### Demo